# How to change text of button when starting a thread?

Tags: java, android

I have this piece of code in `onCreate` method of `MainACtivity` class:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setText("Start");

final baresipThread thread = new baresipThread();

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    boolean running = false;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!running) {
            ((Button)v).setText("Stop");
            thread.start();
            running = true;
        } else {
            thread.kill();
            running = false;
            ((Button)v).setText("Start");
        }
    }
});
```

and baresipThread class looks like this:

```
package com.tutpro.baresip;

public class baresipThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        baresip_start();
    }

    public void kill() {
        baresip_kill();
    }

    public native void baresip_start();
    public native void baresip_kill();

}
```

If I remove `thread.start()`/`thread.kill()` calls from the code, text of the button toggles each time I press it. But if the thread calls are included, there is no change in text (initially `Start`) of the button, when I press it. The thread is started fine.

Why doesn't the text get changed and how to make it happen?

Comment: have you tried calling buttons repaint method after changing text?

Comment: Looks like button object does not have repaint() method.  Also, my question really is, why does calling thread.start() after setText("Stop") causes setText("Stop") to have no effect.

Comment: I'll close this question and make another one.  The real question is why calling of a native C function that never terminates from Java thread makes the whole application unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
 final boolean running = false;
    final baresipThread thread = new baresipThread();
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!running) {
            ((Button)v).setText("Stop");
            thread.start();
            running = true;
        } else {
            thread.kill();
            running = false;
            ((Button)v).setText("Start");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for showing shorter way to invoke setText() calls.  Unfortunately it didn't help with the problem.  The thread calls still nullify the effect of the setText calls.  If I comment out the thread calls, the button text toggles fine at each press.

Comment: I just added that code to the original question.  It tuns out that this may not have anything to do with threads, since I have the same issue if I replace thread.start() call with direct call the native method baresip_start().  That native method runs forever unless user terminates it.

Comment: The question was answered in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734275/whole-java-application-becomes-unresponsive-after-c-function-call-from-java-thre