# whole Java application becomes unresponsive after C function call from Java thread

Tags: java, android-ndk

I have defined this kind of Android Java class, where native function `baresipStart()` never terminates:

```
package com.tutpro.baresip;

public class BaresipThread extends Thread {

    public void start() {
        baresipStart();
    }

    public void kill() {
        baresipStop();
    }

    public native void baresipStart();
    public native void baresipStop();

}
```

I then call its `start()` function from another Java class:

```
BaresipThread thread;
thread = new BaresipThread();
thread.start();
```

The result is that `baresipStart()` function starts to run fine, but rest of the  application becomes completely unresponsive.

Why is that and how to fix the code so that `baresipStart()` function runs in the background without stopping all other activity?

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.start()` is responsible for actually creating the new thread of execution and setting it running.  By overriding it as you did, you cause it to instead run `baresipStart()`, *in the thread that invokes `start()`*.

Instead of overriding `start()`, you should override `run()`.  This method is what defines the work to be performed in the new thread of execution.

Furthermore, if native method `baresipStart()` indeed *never* returns then you have a problem.  Your application cannot terminate while it has any active threads.  Supposing that you intend for `baresipStop()` to cause the thread to finish, you should arrange for `baresipStart()` to return (or to throw an unchecked exception) when execution is terminated by an invocation of `baresipStop()`.  Do be aware, however, that those native methods need to be thread-safe, because they will, perforce, be invoked by different Java threads.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your explanation.  I got the new baresip thread started by removing BaresipThread object altogether and replacing the three lines above with this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        baresipStart();
    }
}).start();
```

User can stop the resulting process via its user interface after which the application is terminated.